# Orion ESM jettison imagery

Tags: orion-spacecraft, artemis-1

The Orion, among others, had a camera inside the CMA (Crew Module Adapter) looking up at the heat shield to image the separation of the ESM (European Service Module). Has any footage or imagery from this camera during Artemis 1 been released?

[image]

(Image [source](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/nasa-s-artemis-i-cameras-to-offer-new-views-of-orion-earth-moon))